# can not plot when time goes from 12 to 1 properly with matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot

I can not find how to properly plot the time when the time changes from **12** to **1** with **matplotlib**. I am taking the time from a text file and trying to plot it against another column in that file. The text file looks like this:

```
1,    12:58:39,      1.903     0.002     0.000     0.000
2,    12:58:41,      3.888     0.003     0.000     0.000
3,    12:58:43,      6.287     0.005     0.000     0.000
...
39,    12:59:55,     55.512     0.066     0.000     0.000
40,    12:59:57,     54.850     0.068     0.000     0.000
41,    12:59:59,     53.940     0.069     0.000     0.000
42,    01:00:01,     52.865     0.071     0.000     0.000
43,    01:00:03,     52.368     0.073     0.000     0.000
44,    01:00:05,     51.954     0.075     0.000     0.000
45,    01:00:06,     57.497     0.059     0.000     0.00

etc..
```

This is my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt   
import matplotlib.dates as mdate
from io import StringIO
from matplotlib.dates import bytespdate2num
import numpy as np

with open('C:/Users/example/{}.txt'.format(TestNumber)) as fh:
    io = StringIO(fh.read().replace(',', '\t'))

    e1, time, e2, e3, e4, e5 = np.loadtxt(io, unpack=True,converters={1:bytespdate2num('%H:%M:%S')})

    fig, ax = plt.subplots()

        # Plot the date using plot_date 
    ax.plot_date(time, e2,'-')

    # Choose your xtick format string
    date_fmt = '%H:%M:%S'

        # Use a DateFormatter to set the data to the correct format.
    date_formatter = mdate.DateFormatter(date_fmt)
    ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(date_formatter)

        # Sets the tick labels diagonal so they fit easier.
    fig.autofmt_xdate()

    ax.set_xlabel('Time')

    fig.savefig('pfig1.png')`
```

When ran with times that do not change from 12 to 1 it plots properly and looks like so 
[image]

When ran with times that go from 12 to 1 it plots something like the following, which is incorrect.
Plot with time switch from 12 to 1:

[image]

Is there a fix for this?

Comment: If switching from AM to PM seems to be a problem, why don't you include some PM lines in your sample input.

Comment: From the file input, how do you know if it is am or pm? There seems to be no marker indicating that.

Comment: The plot seems correct. When going from 12:59 to 01:00 this is a 12 hour jump back in time and this is correctly represented in the plot.